# Excell IF statement not returning the correct value

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have the following expression where I'm trying to change the value of a cell using whatever value another cell has.

```
=CONCAT(IF(F2 < 3; 0; IF(OR(F2 > 3; F2 < 8); 45; 90)); "€")
```

What I don't understand is, if I choose a value of 9 in F2, it doesn't change the value to 90 has it should.

Comment: Change your OR to AND.

Comment: I've added an answer describing the reason why it matters @F.Dinis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `OR(F2 > 3; F2 < 8)` statement is satisfied. That's why 45 is being chosen and not 90.

The `OR` means:

1. If F2 > 3, choose 45
2. If F2 is not > 3, then check if F2 < 8. If F2 is less than 8, choose 45
3. If F2 is not < 8, choose 90

F2 is 9. It meets the first criteria and therefore 45 is chosen.

You could `AND(F2 > 3; F2 < 8)` to get what you want.

The `AND` means:

1. If F2 > 3, then check the next clause
2. If F2 < 8, then choose 45
3. If both conditions are not met, choose 90

Comment: @F.Dinis no worries. I did notice that you haven't marked any answer to your previously asked questions as accepted. It'll be great if you mark a response to your previous question and this question as answered to give closure to your question.